# template not working in django

Tags: python, django

im following a django tutorial on how to make a blog, and we are at the template tags, the thing is, only the head is showing up and not the articles that i placed into my template, this is my code:

views

```
 from django.shortcuts import render
 from.models import Narticle


  def narticle_list(request):
    narticle= Narticle.objects.all().order_by('date')
    return render(request,'narticle/narticle_list', {'narticle': narticle})
```

template narticle_list

```
     <!DOCTYPE html>
          <html>
              <head>
                <meta charset="utf-8">
                  <title>Narticle</title>
                     </head>
                           <body>
                             <h1>narticle_list</h1>

                               <div class="narticle">


               <h2> <a href="#">{{Narticle.title}}</a> </h2>

               <p>{{Narticle.body}}</p>

                <p>{{Narticle.date}}</p>


                  </div>

                  </body>
             </html>
```

in case you want to see my urls

```
   from django.conf.urls import url, include
   from django.contrib import admin
   from. import views



    urlpatterns = [
     url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
      url(r'^narticle/', include ('narticle.urls')),
      url(r'^about/$', views.about),
      url(r'^$',views.homepage),
```

url for narticle

```
    from django.conf.urls import url
    from. import views



      urlpatterns = [

           url(r'^$',views.narticle_list),

          ]
```

when i request the narticle url, my articles are not showing up, just the header which is "narticle_list"

Answer (score 2):

You are passing a collection into the context of the template. This collection acts like a python list, so you need to iterate over it. You can do this with template logic:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
     <html>
         <head>
             <meta charset="utf-8">
              <title>Narticle</title>
         </head>
         <body>
             <h1>narticle_list</h1>

             {% for a in narticle %}

                 <div class="narticle">

                     <h2> <a href="#">{{a.title}}</a> </h2>

                     <p>{{a.body}}</p>

                     <p>{{a.date}}</p>

                 </div>

            {% endfor %}

        </body>
     </html>
```

To clarify, the collection is what you get from `Narticle.objects.all().order_by('date')`. You refer to the `narticle` from the template context in the `{% for a in narticle %}` line. Be sure to close the loop with `{% endfor %}`. You can access properties or attributes as you have already done in your example with dot notation. Everything else looks like it should work.